# Can you describe every number as a handful of small recurring operations and some input?

Tags: algorithms

Let's say that I would like to describe every number from 1 to googleplex with a limited number of operations, but including recursion.

So for a random example, I want to describe:
340282366920938463463374607431768211146

I can describe that as the following:

```
input = 2

while_loops = 7

while (while_loops > 0):
    input = input * input
    while_loops = while_loops - 1

input = input - 310

print(input)
```

Is it possible to represent all integers between 1 and googleplex with similarly simple steps?

Is there a way to measure how complex the algorithms would need to get to be able to describe every number between those two?

Is there a way to quickly determine what those algorithms are?

What field of mathematics would study this question? Are there any big name papers?

Comment: Umm.... like add $1$ repeatedly?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork

Right, except in that case to get to googleplex you'd need to use the number googleplex.  Let's say there's some arbitrary limit, like 3 digits for any input number.

Comment: As @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC:  Kolmogorov proved that you need as many bits to describe an arbitrary number as the number of bits in the number itself.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC  Perfect, thank you!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: I know almost nothing about Kolmogorov complexity other than it sounds like what the OP was asking about, so that's an interesting result. Also, I'd guess that the OPer is going to be disappointed looking for results about how to determine minimal algorithms. But at least they now know some terms to include in their searches. :-)